# how to split a column into two columns in R

Tags: r

I have an input file with 30 rows and a column. I have to split the column into two columns and have to split it in such a way that final output must be having two columns with  equal number of digits.
 As an example: suppose File is in the following format.

```
1111111111
1010101010
1110011010
1011111111
```

and the output should be

```
11111  11111
10101  01010
11100  11010
10111  11111
```

Comment: Is this in a data.frame in R?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach using `read.fwf` (read fixed-width-format):

```
## make a fake file called 'x'
x <- tempfile() 

cat("1111111111
1010101010
1110011010
1011111111", sep = "\n", file = x)

# read just the first line to find out how many characters
# there are in each line. You can use this to determine your widths
Width <- nchar(readLines(x, n = 1)) 

## Use read.fwf
read.fwf(file = x, widths = rep(Width/2, 2), 
         colClasses = "character")
#      V1    V2
# 1 11111 11111
# 2 10101 01010
# 3 11100 11010
# 4 10111 11111
```

---

You can also use `substr`:

```
A <- readLines(x)
cbind(V1 = substr(A, 1, 5), V2 = substr(A, 6, 10))
```

Or, without hard-coding the values for `substr`:

```
apply(matrix(c(1, Width/2, Width/2+1, Width), ncol = 2), 
      2, function(y) substr(readLines(x), y[1], y[2]))
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 secs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame, the problem is straightforward. The package `tidyr` contains the handy `separate` function:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("1111111111
1010101010
1110011010
1011111111"))

library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

separate(df,V1,into = c("one","two"), sep = 5)

    one   two
1 11111 11111
2 10101 01010
3 11100 11010
4 10111 11111
```

If you don't always have exactly 10 values, you can wrap `separate` in a little function and pass in the actual lengths:

```
separator <- function(l = 5) separate(df,V1,into = c("one","two"), sep = l)

nstr <- unique(sapply(df$V1,str_length))

stopifnot(length(nstr) == 1) 
separator(nstr %/% 2)

    one   two
1 11111 11111
2 10101 01010
3 11100 11010
4 10111 11111
```

Not the use of `%/%` integer division.  This will make sure that the value of `sep` is always an integer, though for odd numbers it will mean inequal widths in the results.

As Ananda fortold in the comments, this is faster than his (awesome) `read.fwf` approach:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(read.fwf(file = x, widths = rep(Width/2, 2), 
                        colClasses = "character"),
               separator())

Unit: microseconds
                                                                   expr     min       lq   median      uq
 read.fwf(file = x, widths = rep(Width/2, 2), colClasses = "character") 833.863 872.6145 891.4575 915.930
                                                            separator() 134.959 150.9120 167.2690 185.702
      max neval
 1273.357   100
 2748.900   100
```

Comment: You assume fixed width here

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I thought that was the assumption that we were working with, though on re-reading, it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I meant that he assumes that the rows are of width 10, but from the question it seems that the OP wants it to work for any width

Comment: @DavidArenburg, ahh. Yes. That's why I had the `readLines(., n = 1)` part in my answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yep, "he" tried to answer the question simply.  Thankfully OP has AnandaMatho's excellent answer instead!

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult to convert this to a more responsive answer. How does this work as a general replacement for `read.fwf` (which I always find painfully slow)? Any experiments? Do the widths translate easily? (+1)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I tried a little experiment to see.  This is one simple way to automate the definition of `sep`.  I had a harder time than I expected extending it to rows of variable length, but that is very different from what OP seems to need, anyway.